# How do I add values in an array of arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays with four integer elements like this:

```
arrays = [[a1,b1,c1,d1],[a2,b2,c2,d2],[a3,b3,c3,d3]]
```

I want to add these three arrays. The result should be in one array like:

```
result = [a1+a2+a3,b1+b2+b3,c1+c2+c3,d1+d2+d3]
```

I tried but not able to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>> arrays = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
>> arrays.transpose.map { |xs| xs.inject :+ }
=> [6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Comment: falsetru you really rockss it work for me thanks..But can you please explain { |xs| xs.inject :+ }. I mean what is we doing here..

Comment: @sumitdhakad, According to [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation, specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator.

Comment: @sumitdhakad, [x, y, z].inject(:+) yield sum of x,y,z.

Comment: thanks for the information actually i am new to stackoverflow and dont know much about it..will learn it over time.....

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Rails, this will work:

```
arrays.transpose.map &:sum
```

Comment: Earlier i was writing logic for this cause i dont know about transpose but it really makes thing easy for us thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3] 
b = [4, 5, 6] 
c = [7, 8, 9]

[a, b, c].transpose.map { |x| x.reduce :+ } 

=> [12, 15, 18]
```

For further clarification see "[Some Array magic using transpose, map and reduce](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/18842314838/some-array-magic-using-transpose-map-and-reduce)".

Comment: When adding a link, whether it's on Stack Overflow, or a HTML page, don't say "Click here". Instead, [give the reader a hint what the link contains](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere) and "[Link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text)".

Comment: @All As you can see my reputation I am beginner to rails and stackoverflow too. i just started my carrier as an software developer so dont know how to react to the solution and how to ask question..... why i am writing all this because seems like in your previous comment someone unvote my question and not feels that i have really this issue..

Comment: @Sumit : Here, I am not hurting you. Consecutively you tried to accept all answers. That's why I asked about this. Anyways welcome to Rails team !!!